# What element to use if I only need an placement target element

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to show a flyout at a specific place. I want to specify a placement target element in XAML, but I want to make sure I am using the "lightest" element possible, given that I don't want that element to ever be visible or interacted with.

Is there a "recommended" or "correct" element to use? If not, what would be the "lightest" element to use? Or am I overthinking this and should just use a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show a flyout at a specific place.

The place of FrameworkElements are based on the panel that you are using to hold them. If you want to show your flyout based on a FrameworkElement being placed in a specific place, you can use [Canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to position your FrameworkElement.

> I want to specify a placement target element in XAML, but I want to make sure I am using the "lightest" element possible.

[Flyout.ShowAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.showat.aspx) takes FrameworkElement as it's placement target. So I think the "lightest" element would be an empty custom FrameworkElement like below:

```
public class MyElement:FrameworkElement
{
}
```

And you can put it into XAML and use Canvas to position it:

```
<Page
  x:Class="PopupSample.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:PopupSample"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">

<Canvas>
    <Button Name="btnClick" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="500" Click="btnClick_Click">Click Me</Button>
    <local:MyElement x:Name="myEle" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="100"></local:MyElement>
</Canvas>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Flyout flyout = new Flyout();
        TextBlock tbContent = new TextBlock
        {
            Text= "this is a flyout content"
        };
        flyout.Content = tbContent;
        flyout.ShowAt(myEle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Grid` is a pretty light element, it's just a simple `Panel`-derived class without any child elements. `Button` is a `Control`, meaning it has a template which will create many child elements that make up its visual appearance.

Are you saying you want to use a dummy element just for the purpose of specifying the position of the flyout which you will show programmatically? If you want to avoid the element altogether, then maybe a `Popup` would be a better choice.